# How to distinguish hits of several should clauses

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with several "should" clauses:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "<condition1>"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "query_string": {
                                "query": "<condition1>"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
        }
    },
    "size": 1000,
    "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I find out which query results were produced by condition1, and which by condition2? Is it possible to inject a field with different values for different conditions, or distinguish hits in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html#search-request-named-queries-and-filters) to achieve this.

```
{ 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "<condition1>",
                        "_name": "sub_query_1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "<condition1>",
                        "_name": "sub_query_2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You result will then contain a `matched_filters` array with either `sub_query_1`, `sub_query_2`, or both in it.

**Update**

Play link: https://www.found.no/play/gist/af1a1fa2b5cf3aa279b1

Comment: I've tried this; the query is executed without any error messages, but result is exactly the same as before. Nothing new added.

Comment: Which elasticsearch version are you on? Named queries exists only from 0.90.4 upwards.

Comment: 0.90.5 (I guess it would return an error message, if I used an unknown query clause)

Comment: You can compare with this play: https://www.found.no/play/gist/af1a1fa2b5cf3aa279b1
(second query)
there, each hit has a matched_queries attribute